# regex doesn't seem to work on the input given as expected

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex, python-2.7

My regex doesn't seem to work as expected, can someone help me fixing it?

```
import re
a = """
xyz # (.C           (0),
       .H           (1)
              )
  mv [F-1:0] (/*AUTOINST*/

except_check
          #(
            .a        (m),
            .b        (w),
            .c        (x),
            .d        (1),
            .e        (1)
        )
        data_check
           (// Outputs

abc
      #(
        .a    (b::c)
    )
    mask
       (/*AUTOINST*/
"""
op = re.findall(r'^\s*(\w+)\s*$\n(?:^\s*[^\w\s].*$\n)*^\s*(\w+)\s*\(', a, re.MULTILINE)
for i in op:
    print(i)
```

This is the output I get:

```
('except_check', 'data_check')
('abc', 'mask')
```

This is the expected output:

```
('xyz', 'mv')
('except_check', 'data_check')
('abc', 'mask')
```

Somehow, the regex doesn't work for first block of input and works fine for other two blocks of input.

Comment: Well, you also have `[F-1:0]` in the first block which is not considered in your regular expression.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a regex with the minimal changes:

```py
^\s*(\w+)(?:\s*[^\w\s].*$\n)*^\s*(\w+)[^()]*\(
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/sAbuRN/1/).

The `\s*$\n(?:^\s*[^\w\s]` part is replaced with `(?:\s*[^\w\s]`, as your first block does not contain a line break.

At the end, `\s*\(` is replaced with `[^()]*\(` because there are chars other than whitespace between the word you want to extract and a `(` char.

*Details*:

- `^` - start of a line (granted you use `re.M`)
- `\s*` - zero or more whitespaces
- `(\w+)` - Group 1: one or more word chars
- `(?:\s*[^\w\s].*\n)*`  - zero or more occurrences of zero or more whitespaces, a special char other than `_`, the rest of the line and an LF char
- `^` - start of a line
- `\s*` - zero or more whitespaces
- `(\w+)` - Group 2: one or more word chars
- `[^()]*` - zero or more chars other than `(` and `)`
- `\(` - a `(` char.

Or, I think you can leverage the recursion feature available in the PyPi regex. Run `pip install regex` in the terminal/console and then

```py
import regex
a = 'your_string_here'
rx = r'^\s*(\w+)\s*#\s*(\((?:[^()]++|(?2))*\))\s*(\w+)'
matches = [(x.group(1), x.group(3)) for x in regex.finditer(rx, a, regex.M)]
```

Here is the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/BNGGYT/1). It matches:

- `^` - start of a line
- `\s*` - zero or more whitespaces
- `(\w+)` - Group 1: one or more word chars
- `\s*#\s*` - a `#` enclosed with zero or more whitespaces
- `(\((?:[^()]++|(?2))*\))` - Group 2: a `(` char, then any zero or more occurrences of any one or more chars other than `(` and `)` or Group 2 pattern, and then a `)`
- `\s*` - zero or more whitespaces
- `(\w+)` - Group 2: one or more word chars.

Answer (score 0):

"(\w+)\s+#\s?(\D*\S*\D*\s*\d?\W+)\s*(\w+)"gm

use this works
you can further simplify